# TypeScript 1.8 relative module name resolution in AMD style modules with RequireJS 2.1

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, amd, typescript-typings

I am trying to use TypeScript in a part of a legacy JS system. 
In this system, many applications exist that get executed in a RequireJS environment where the main.js will execute when that application is launched.  I have created this structure

```
App1/
   main.js
   app.ts
   Modules/
      myModule.ts
      Models/
         model1.js
         model2.js
```

Models are generated codes and have to stay as .JS files. 
Models should be required by 'Require' statements from different .ts modules.

I know how to use something like this in a Declaration file in modules folder to let the .ts files compile.

```
   declare module "Models/model1" { var x:any; export = x;}
```

But the code will not execute because this will create such an AMD module definition for myModule.ts

```
define(["require","exports","Models/model1", function(require,exports,model){ ...
```

but the path gets resolved by Require.JS as

```
 http://mysite/Models/model1.js
```

which is missing path sections because path is relative and has to be absolute from RequireJS's context root. I can not have models as TS because they are generated files. They don't compile just by renaming to .ts 
also non-relative paths are not usable due to different ways the application runs in harnesses, production and unit-test setups.

**Question:** Is there a way to get TypeScript to generate relative paths for JavaScript (.js) modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into [Triple-Slash Directives](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)? As of TypeScript 2.0 this has been deprecated for `import "moduleName"` but should work for older versions:

> `/// <amd-dependency path="x" />` informs the compiler about a non-TS
>   module dependency that needs to be injected in the resulting module’s
>   require call.
>
> The amd-dependency directive can also have an optional name property;
>   this allows passing an optional name for an amd-dependency:
>
> ```
> /// <amd-dependency path="legacy/moduleA" name="moduleA"/>
> declare var moduleA:MyType
> moduleA.callStuff()
> ```
>
> Generated JS code:
>
> ```
> define(["require", "exports", "legacy/moduleA"], function (require, exports, moduleA) {
>     moduleA.callStuff()
> });
> ```